# No module named 'dash'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not able to access dash library in python in fact I've download that library then also.

```
C:\Data processing>python3 dashboard.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Data processing\dashboard.py", line 1, in <module>
    import dash
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash'
```

I've installed with:

```
C:\Data processing>pip install dash
Requirement already satisfied: dash in c:\users\vatsa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=1.0.2 in c:\users\vatsa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from dash) (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: flask-compress in c:\users\vatsa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from dash) (1.13)
Requirement already satisfied: plotly in c:\users\vatsa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from dash) (5.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: dash-renderer==1.2.2 in c:\users\vatsa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from dash) (1.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: dash-core-components==1.6.0 in c:\users\vatsa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from dash) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: dash-html-components==1.0.2 in c:\users\vatsa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from dash) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: dash-table==4.5.1 in c:\users\vatsa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from dash) (4.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\vatsa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from dash) (0.18.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=2.2.2 in c:\users\vatsa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=1.0.2->dash) (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.0 in c:\users\vatsa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=1.0.2->dash) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.0 in c:\users\vatsa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=1.0.2->dash) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=8.0 in c:\users\vatsa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from Flask>=1.0.2->dash) (8.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: brotli in c:\users\vatsa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from flask-compress->dash) (1.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: tenacity>=6.2.0 in c:\users\vatsa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from plotly->dash) (8.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\vatsa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from plotly->dash) (23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\vatsa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from click>=8.0->Flask>=1.0.2->dash) (0.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in c:\users\vatsa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=3.0->Flask>=1.0.2->dash) (2.1.2)
```

How to figure out this problem should I need to give any permission??

Comment: Can you show the output of `pip --version`? also, make sure you don't have `pip` and `pip3` installed for different python versions.

Comment: Can you please tell me what Python version are you using? The simplest way to check is to type `python3` in your terminal and press enter.

Comment: @Elia here is my output of pip --version --> `C:\Windows\system32>pip --version pip 23.1 from C:\Users\vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)`

Comment: @Rukon my python version is `3.10.11`

Comment: How about `pip show dash`?

Comment: Here are output of  **`pip show dash`**

`Name: dash
Version: 1.7.0
Summary: A Python framework for building reactive web-apps. Developed by Plotly.
Home-page: https://plot.ly/dash
Author: Chris Parmer
Author-email: chris@plot.ly
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\vatsa\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages
Requires: dash-core-components, dash-html-components, dash-renderer, dash-table, Flask, flask-compress, future, plotly
Required-by:
`

Comment: Maybe @Elia's suggestion of different python versions is the issue. Does `python dashboard.py` (without the 3) work?

Comment: @Tim it give me More error:
`PS C:\Data processing> python .\dashboard.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Data processing\dashboard.py", line 1, in <module>
    import dash
  File "C:\Users\vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dash\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .dash import Dash, no_update  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 21, in <module>   
    from werkzeug.debug.tbtools import get_current_traceback
`

Comment: `ImportError: cannot import name 'get_current_traceback' from 'werkzeug.debug.tbtools' (C:\Users\vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\tbtools.py)`

Comment: Looks like package version conflicts. Try `pip install -U dash`. I'm experimenting with this in a virtual environment and will let you know what I find out.

Comment: Yep, dash==1.7.0 is not compatible with your installed werkzeug version (2.2.2). You just needed to install the latest version of dash (currently 2.9.3) as @vatsal_mangukiya has answered: `python3 -m pip install -U dash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this way it may help you.

```
python3 -m pip install dash
```